Помогите найти ошибку! Ошибка при добавлении связанных сущностей
public class DBUser
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Family { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Department {  get; set; }
public string Position {  get; set; }
public int? factoryID { get; set; }
public DbFactoryModel Factory { get; set; }
public ICollection<DbContactsModel> UserContacts { get; set; }
}



public class DbFactoryModel
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string Address {  get; set; } 
     public string Phones { get; set; }
     public string Fax {  get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<DbUserModel> _Employees { get; set; }
 }

Метод для вставки нового User:
public int AddUser(int factoryId, DbUserModel model, List<DbContactsModel> userContacts)
     {
         if (model == null) return 0;
         using (var context = new PLContext())
         {
             int c = context.Users.ToList().Where(fk => fk.Family.Contains(model.Family) 
                                 && fk.FirstName.Contains(model.FirstName)
                                 && fk.LastName.Contains(model.LastName) 
                                 ).Count();
             if (c == 0)
             {
                 context.Users.Attach(model);
                 context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
                 
             }
             else
                 MessageBox.Show("Сотрудник уже есть в базе");
             
             if (factoryId != 0 && factoryId != -1)
             {
                 var factory = context.Factories.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == factoryId);
                 factory._Employees.Add(model);
             }
             
             context.SaveChanges();
     
             if (userContacts.Count() != 0)
             {
                 var index = context.Entry(model).CurrentValues.GetValue<int>("Id");
                 var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(fk => fk.Id == index);
    
                 foreach (var item in userContacts)
                 {
                     context.Contacts.Attach(item);
                     context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                     user.UserContacts.Add(item);
                 }
             }
    
             return context.SaveChanges();
         }
     }

При выполнении всё работает нормально до момента user.UserContacts.Add(item);
Не могу понять, почему работников добавляет, а контакты нет.
Выдает исключение
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Просто задайте значение коллекции UserContacts.

Вообще, тут ошибка на ошибке и ошибкой погоняет. Вам бы ревью кода запросить.

Ревью кода - это хорошо, когда есть более опытные товарищи. В моем случае, я самоучка, пишу под свои нужды

Ревью можете запросить здесь, добавив метку "Инспекция-кода".

У Вас коллекция не инициализорована.
Попробуйте сделать:
public ICollection<DbContactsModel> UserContacts { get; set; } = new List<DbContactsModel>();


Спасибо, всё заработало
